# How can I route users to different functions based on their privileges in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing, access-control

This may have been asked before, and I have seen similar solutions... Perhaps I am thinking about this incorrectly.

I would like to have one link called user/edit if the user is an admin it should route to admin_ if they are a basic user it should route to user_ etc... Is there a way to do this in a slick way?

I have seen solutions that kind of do the opposite like type in user/admin_edit and it takes you to user/edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to take a look at prefix routing.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/544/Prefix-Routing

Combine this with Cakes built in Auth/ACL and you should have no problem.